# Adding a new colorscheme without Root permission

Tags: linux, vim, permissions, vi, csh

I tried to add new colorschemes in /usr/share/vim/vim70/colors
but it seems that I need Root permission to do so.
Is there any way to do it without root permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to add the color scheme system wide. You need root permissions to do that. Try adding it to your personal vim config. Like

`mv colorscheme.vim ~/.vim/colors/`

you may need to create this folder with

`mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors`